# Moving along 2D vector (tower defense) in c++

Tags: c++, game-physics

I'm writing a simple tower defence and I'm stuck on a bit where my tower has to shoot enemy.

With this code:

```
void Bullet::move(int x, int y, int speed) 
{

    Punkt delta = {(x + speed) - this->x, (y + speed) - this->y};
    if (abs(delta.x) > 1 && abs(delta.y) > 1)
    {
        this->x += delta.x / this->speed;
        this->y += delta.y / this->speed;
    }
    else
    {
        this->dead = true;
    }
}
```

Where method arguments are target position and speed. It's supposed to move bullet along vector till it reaches the target but the vector changes because the target is moving. For now the bullet ends up like this (black is the tower, blue is the bullet and red is enemy)

[image: error]

And I know the problem is that my bullet is targeting something that already moved so my question is - how to improve this code so it works properly? I don't know how to wrap my head around vectors and balistics so thanks in advance for keeping it simple.

Comment: Might be a better question for gamedev.

Comment: Why are you using integer arithmetic? `x`, `Bullet::x`, `delta.x` and `speed` are all integers, which may lead to unexpected results: if `this->speed` is bigger than `delta.x` and `delta.y`, your bullet will stop moving even though it hasn't reached its target!

Comment: SDL axis is in integer, I can't use float, or can I?

Comment: @user1899044 Use floats to perform the computation, then convert the result to integers implicitly. That way the computations are more accurate and they round only at the end. It's best if you store the sprite positions as floats, then convert only to ints when passing to SDL so that rounding/truncating happens only when drawing.

Comment: You need to learn a lot more math if you want to be an effective programmer. If you're not comfortable with motion at a constant speed and finding intersecting points and angles, that will really harm the quality of the code you produce.

Comment: @David I don't want to be a programmer, but I have an assigment to finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reasonable solution to this problem that I've seen used before is as follows:

1. Do your best to predict where a good collision point will be for the bullet and enemy. A naive approach would be to make your prediction simply the current enemy position.
2. Fire the bullet at the predicted position
3. When the bullet gets to the predicted position, make the bullet disappear, play the damage animation, and lower the enemy's health - regardless of whether the bullet actually hits

This way if you're clever enough with your math, it will look good. But otherwise, the game will still work properly.

This approach is also more robust if it's possible for the enemies to change speed (for example they get slowed down by special terrain, or an area-of-effect turret) after you fire at them.

Answer (score 2):

If you are shooting a moving target you need to target the location where it will be in the time it takes the bullet to reach it, then you have two known positions so you know the vector.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I've looked a bit on gamedev forums and I got the solution (that I even managed to understand). It was all about calculating properly (converting to float was necesary as everyone said). Here is the code for the lazy:

```
float dx = x - this->x;
float dy = y - this->y;
float dx2, dy2;
float distance;
float vx, vy;

distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
dx2 = dx / distance;
dy2 = dy / distance;

vx = dx2 * this->speed;
vy = dy2 * this->speed;

if (distance > 10) // 10 is hitbox size
{
    this->x += vx; // still float, its converted to int when applying to surface
    this->y += vy;
}
else
{
    this->dead = true;
}
```